# A proposed follow-up to boost Writing Challenge and Promote Writers.SE together

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I bumped into a few **old** interesting meta questions/posts: [What questions should be compiled into Writers.SE ebook?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/what-questions-should-we-compile-into-a-writers-se-ebook) and [Writing Contests](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/lets-hold-a-contest-october-2013). Alternatively, I am also witnessing **newer** trends and participation in [Writing Challenge](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/writing-challenge-something-new-26-sep-2017-17-oct-2017?cb=1), [Publication Announcements](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/would-publication-announcements-be-appropriate-for-meta), [National Novel Writing contest](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/what-are-we-doing-for-national-novel-writing-month-this-year?cb=1) etc.

After going through all these posts, I think we can actually do more to attract newer audiences (as well as a good amount of readers).

SE newsletters don't include meta posts. Do they? I went [here](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) and confirmed this. This means, the fun writing activities like Writing challenges, Contests and Publication announcements that happen on meta don't totally reach out in emails and subscribers. I don't know the number and extent of newsletter subscribers for this site, but I feel that it might not be encouraging more and newer audiences.

Having said that, **I propose to re-start e-book publishing** (I don't know the status of e-book now) which involves not only great questions of the main site, but also the fun activities happening for writers on meta. Meta is/was not used this way in other sites and since Writing proudly uses it as a part of [Writers' participation](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1354/22084) (PS: **see only the comments of the linked answer**) and sites' all-round development, we can give it a try. We might start a blog. (If there is none yet?)

Comment: I also toyed around with creating an ebook at the time, but I didn't feel like the Q&A worked well in ebook format -- OTOH, that doesn't mean it couldn't be done well! I'd love to see a new effort :)

Comment: Also, note that Amazon doesn't support free ebooks any more, and visibility and discoverability are really hard problems :-/ I'd love to see a showcase, but I don't know how likely it'd be to drive traffic.